# ReactCSSTransitionGroup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, animation, reactjs

I have some trouble with ReactCSSTransitionGroup. I want to show up some kind of Modal form with some fancy animations when user clicks the button on the page. This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppConfig from './AppConfig';

export default class AppTop extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { openConfig: false };
    }
    toggleConfig() {
        this.setState({ openConfig: !this.state.openConfig });
    }
    render() {
        // only shows up openConfig is true
        const domAppConfig = this.state.openConfig ? <AppConfig ... /> : '';

        return (
            <div>
                ... //some elements
                <button onClick={this.toggleConfig.bind(this)}>Config</button>
                { domAppConfig }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is AppTop component. You can see the button component inside of render, on click this, openConfig state will toggle. Now this is AppConfig component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

export default class AppConfig extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName="anim-app-config"
                transitionEnterTimeout={300}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
            >
                <div id="app-config">
                    <h1>App Config</h1>
                    <p>Helloworld!</p>
                </div>
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        );
    }
}
```

component is quite simple, just print some texts. And this is the style of '.anim-app-config':

```
.anim-app-config-enter {
    opacity: .1;
}
.anim-app-config-enter.anim-app-config-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
.anim-app-config-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}
.anim-app-config-leave.anim-app-config-leave-active {
    opacity: .1;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

when I run this App, animation doesn't work. Just component shows up and hides immediately, without animations. I searched about this, and I tried adding a key into AppConfig Component, it didn't worked. Wrapping one more div didn't work either. Adding transitionAppear={true} also not worked for me.

Am I wrong using ReactCSSTransitionGroup component? Or am I something missed? It is hard to add animation on React to me, so please gimme some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have  ReactCSSTransitionGroup in your Apptop because ie the point where it will render or not. MAking it inside AppConfig wont have any animation since it will render it as a straight component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppConfig from './AppConfig';

export default class AppTop extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { openConfig: false };
    }
    toggleConfig() {
        this.setState({ openConfig: !this.state.openConfig });
    }
    render() {
        // only shows up openConfig is true
        const domAppConfig = this.state.openConfig ? <AppConfig ... /> : '';

        return (
            <div>
                ... //some elements
                <button onClick={this.toggleConfig.bind(this)}>Config</button>
                        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName="anim-app-config"
                transitionEnterTimeout={300}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
            >
                {domAppconfig}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You must provide the key attribute for all children of ReactCSSTransitionGroup, even when only rendering a single item. This is how React will determine which children have entered, left, or stayed.

Try adding something like `key="1"` to `<div id="app-config">` and see if it helps.